# Short story: Person uploaded as digital online persona after death "speaks" to exponentially growing audience

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story that I believe I read online about 5 years ago, though I may be off by a few years either way. It is told from the perspective of a person who seems to have been brought back to digital life after dying, and who has been given a kind of chat channel in cyberspace with which to interact.

The entire story is the person "talking" on this chat channel to the audience, which seems to be growing exponentially over time. The person is able to observe at least the audience count and may be able to glean other information somehow through electronic senses, but the overall tone is one of confusion as the narrator tries to adapt to his or her situation.

The story is written in short segments and has a stream-of-consciousness feel, though I think it's entirely composed of things "said" and not an internal dialogue of the narrator. He or she keeps referring to the audience as "you" or "you all" and, if I recall correctly, is noticing that the date (which can also be observed somehow) keeps skipping ahead into the future at a rapid rate. (Perhaps the narrator is "shut off" or "paused" between segments?) The story ends on a note of despair as the narrator cries out to the growing audience, which he or she can no longer understand.

I don't think it's a very long story, perhaps 5 pages or so if printed out. Again, I'm reasonably sure that I read this online, but it may not have been a typical "professional" site (e.g. Clarkesworld). However, I don't think the author was totally unknown, either, so perhaps someone else here will recognize this story.

EDIT: User LAK's suggestion below sounded promising, but I have never read that anthology, and the three most likely titles ("People Are Reading What You Are Writing", "The Last Man Standing" and "Deep Blue Dreams") don't seem to ever have been published anywhere else, so I don't think it was one of them.

Comment: I read a story like this in a Lovecraft-inspired anthology where a simulated Lovecraft himself is brought back, running on a computer.  Might have been the *Future Lovecraft* anthology.  Unfortunately, my copy is packed away somewhere so I can't check to be sure.